# Cannot build gradle prroject with gradle --scan option

Tags: gradle

I have problem with Gradle --scan option. I followed this tutorial: https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds/?_ga=2.62865448.54080785.1533153183-1753091300.1533153183, but unfortunately when I execute ./gradlew {some-task-name} --scan it fails. I try with ./gradlew --scan and it fails with the same exception. 
The most simple way to reproduce it:
 1. Execute gradle init
 2. ./gradlew --scan (in the same folder)

I cannot understand why gradle cannot find this plugin in its central repo. I use gradle 4.9

The exception is the following:

---

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Auto-applied by using --scan
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.build-scan', version: '1.15.1', artifact: 'com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:1.15.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle:build-scan-plugin:1.15.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s

---

Do not hesitate to ask for additional details.
Thanks in advance for your attention.

P.S. I attach file containing the output of ./gradlew --scan --debug

[result.txt](https://ufile.io/vrc9o)

Comment: Have you read the error message? When it advised you to run with --info or --debug, did you follow that advice? What did you discover?

Comment: @JB Nizet, Thanks for your attention!
Yes, I try to run it with --debug option, but I don't find nothing helpful in the output. I attach a file with the output with --debug option.

Comment: My guesses are: your network or proxy or firewall somehow prevents you to access the gradle repo, or the gradle repo is down, or Java 11 is not supported by gradle yet and causes some issue.

Comment: I am running into the same issue with gradle 5.1.1 version. And I am in company network with all proxy or firewall set ups.

Comment: I got around this by modifying  the pom's groupid from com.gradle to org.gradle and uploading it into local nexus repository.